# Radio Button to open pages

Tags: javascript, radio-button

i have a form with 2 radio buttons and a submit button. Both radio buttons have url of different pages, like one will open google.com and another will open yahoo.com. have selected a radio button and submit the page. i want it to open my url. 
Please help. with HTML and javascript code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself 90k of extra script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function doSubmit(form) {
    var urls = form['url'];
    var i = urls && urls.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (urls[i].checked) {
        window.location = urls[i].value;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  </script>

  <form action="" onsubmit="return doSubmit(this)">
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="http://www.google.com"> Google
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="http://www.yahoo.com"> Yahoo
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Oh, and **never** give a form control a name of "submit" as it will mask the form's submit method. If you must, name it "submitButton" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="http://www.google.com" /> Google
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="http://www.yahoo.com" /> Yahoo
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
    });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Rpzvd/3/

Comment: Note that you need jQuery for this one.

Comment: I think the entire Internet needs JQuery for survival.

Comment: Some web developers do, the internet is quite happy without it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
<?
if ($_POST['submitUrl']){
header('Location:'.$_POST['url']);
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="radio" name="url" value="http://www.google.com"/>Link1<br>
<input type="radio" name="url" value="http://www.yahoo.com"/>Link2<br>
<input type="submit" name"submitUrl" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```