# If radio button checked, then submit to different page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, session

I have this:

```
<form method="post" id="kl" action="step2.php">

<input type="radio" name="rubrik" value="bussines"></input>
<input type="radio" name"rubrik" value="private"></input>

<input type="image" value="submit" src="/images/submit.png" alt="Submit" />

</form>
```

What i bassicaly want is: When the second radio button is checked, to submit the form to step2a.php, a different file. How can i do this? Jquery, Javascript, php?

Comment: You can do this via Javascript of course, but Javascript is not the way to realize this, because it can and will be deactivated in some user's browsers.

The best thing is if you simply do all the checks in step2.php and then redirect the user to the page where he should go, via an appropriate HTTP header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with JavaScript (bind a submit listener that checks the value of the radio button and then sets the action property of the form), but it would be simpler and more reliable to do something (server side) along the lines of:

```
<form ... action="step-selector.php">
```

and

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['rubrik']) && $_POST['rubrik'] == 'bussines') {
        include('step2.php');
    } elseif (isset($_POST['rubrik']) && $_POST['rubrik'] == 'private') {
         include('step2a.php');
    } else {
         include('error-state.php');
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. Just what i needed, exactly how i needed it most. Thank you, Quentin!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by modifying the Form into:

```
<form method="post" id="kl" action="step2.php">

<input type="radio" class="radio" rel="step2.php" name="rubrik" value="bussines"></input>
<input type="radio" class="radio" rel="step2a.php" name"rubrik" value="private"></input>

<input type="image" value="submit" src="/images/submit.png" alt="Submit" />

</form>
```

I added rel attribute to radio buttons. each has a value of the url. I also added a class to get the element with jQuery.

Now, you will need some Javascript, i will use jQuery code:

```
$('.radio').click(function (){
   rad = $(this);
   radRel = rad.attr('rel');
   $('form#kl').attr('action', radRel);
});
```

Comment: `rel` has a defined meaning (which isn't "Attribute to hold arbitrary data for JavaScript") and doesn't appear on input elements. Don't abuse it that way.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways of doing it, depending on what you want exactly.

Check this one out, it might help you get there; [Radio Button to open pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741340/radio-button-to-open-pages)

Answer (score -1):

You can use form.submit() as onclick-handler (not onchange) and change the action, too.

```
<input type="radio" name"rubrik" value="private" onclick="this.parentNode.action='yourOtherFile.php'; this.parentNode.submit()"></input>
```