# How create condition on the Radio Button?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create the conditions to the radio buttons.

when radio button selected Yes, then he would to another page.

when radio button selected No, then he would to another page

can help me? this my code

```
 <label class="control-label center" for="">are you sure to exit?</label>
<div class="column-chekbox-down center">
    <label class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" name="kmb" id="" value="Yes">
      Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
      <input type="radio" name="kmb" id="" value="No">
      No
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: what solutions have you tried?

Comment: this is the link that may help u [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504059/if-radio-button-checked-then-submit-to-different-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
try this solution    
    <script>
           $(function(){
             if($('input[name=kmb]:checked').val() == "yes")
                 window.loaction=" a url";
             else if($('input[name=kmb]:checked').val() == "no")
                 window.loaction=" a url";
           });
    </script>
```

*not tested*

Answer (score 0):

Just set `click` event for each radio button and you you can use `window.location = 'http://www.someurl.com';`

```
$('#no').click(function(){
    alert('You clicked "No"');
    window.location = 'http://google.com';
});

$('#yes').click(function(){
    alert('You clicked "Yes"');
    window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6Yf4/1/)

@John's answer is best if you have another action to trigger the check, such as a form submit. Mine however would happen as soon as you click a radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `JavaScript`, but before that you have to make one change to your `HTML`.

```
<input type="radio" name="kmb" id="YES" value="YES">
<input type="radio" name="kmb" id="NO" values="NO">
```

`Javascript` Code:

```
function redirect()
{
    if(document.getElementById('YES').checked)
    {
         window.location="http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    }
    else
    {
         window.location="http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    }
}
```