# Condition when pressing radio button

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do i make my page do this in particular.

I have 2 choices LBC and PickUp,
If the user selects LBC, it would proceed to the next page to select payment options.
but if the user selects the PickUp radio option, it would be redirected immediately to the last page, since the payment option is no longer applicable.

I have this javascript function that enables a button, but other than that, i have no idea how do do it.

Redirecting the page depending on what radio button is pressed. If LBC no problem, if Pickup proceed to next page after payment page, so it would skip the payment page.

Please help thank you.

```
<form method="post" action="payment.php">

<?php
echo "<table><tr>";
$i = 0;
$qry="SELECT * FROM shipping";
$result= @mysql_query($qry);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    if ($i > 0 && $i % 3 == 0) { 
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>";
?>

                <table width="" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr class="row_submit">
                        <td height="250px" width="300px"><center><label>
                            <input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="$row[ship_name]") echo "checked";?>  value="<?php echo $row['ship_name']; ?>">
                            <!--<img src="../paymentoptions/lbc.png" alt="LBC" class="picture" width="245px" style="margin:10px"/></label></td> -->
                            <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['ship_pic'] ).'"  height="215px"  width="245px" style="margin:10px"/>'; ?>

                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row_submit">
                        <td height="130px" width="300px"><p><?php echo $row['ship_desc']; ?><p></td>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <div id='price'> Additional ₱ <?php echo $row['ship_price']; ?></div></td></tr>
                </table>

  <?php  
    echo "</td>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr></table>";
?>

<br>
                <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="View Shopping Cart" onclick="window.location='shoppingcart.php'"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" disabled="disabled" name="next" value="Proceed to Payment" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

        </form>
```

Comment: Please show the code that you attempted so far and explain what errors it causes

Comment: possible duplicate of [If radio button checked, then submit to different page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504059/if-radio-button-checked-then-submit-to-different-page)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['radio_button_name']['LBC']){
  header('location:lbc_paymentpage.php');
}else{
  header('location:pickuppage.php');
}
```

Comment: where should i put this? next page? or same page?

Comment: There was no code above when I answered. Look at the thread newbiecoder999 posted, I just had a quick scan and it answers your question