# Link out of radio button

Tags: forms, url, hyperlink, submit

is it possible to use a form with some radio buttons for linking to the selected page after submitting? So i selected the first radio-button, hit the buttion submit and got the the url /angebote.html

Thx!

```
<form id="aktion">
          <div class="action-check">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" value="angebote.html" name="suche">
            <label for="suche">Ich suche ein Zimmer</label>
          </div>
          <div class="action-check">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" value="angebotseingabe.html" name="biete">
            <label for="biete">Ich biete ein Zimmer</label>
           </div>
          <div class="action-check">
          <input class="radio" type="radio" value="gesuchseingabe.html" name="gruenden">
          <label for="gruenden">Ich möchte eine WG gründen</label>
         </div>
          <div class="submit_container">
          <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Los geht's">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript like this.

```
<HTML> 
    <HEAD>
         <SCRIPT language="javascript"> 
              function choiceprop(form3) {
                   var url = <!-- check the good case here -->
                   window.location = url;
               } 
          </SCRIPT> 
    </HEAD> 
    <BODY>
        <FORM NAME="formtest">
             <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="choice" VALUE="url1">name1<BR>
             <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="choice" VALUE="url2">name2<BR> 
             <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="choice" VALUE="url3">name3<BR> 
             <INPUT TYPE="button"NAME="but" VALUE="Validate" onClick="choiceprop(formtest)">
        </FORM> 
   </BODY> 
</HTML>
```

Comment: This works like a charm:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741340/radio-button-to-open-pages